# Firefox extension to that add rename feature to download dialog

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

Is there a Firefox extension that add a rename feature (for example a textbox) to Firefox's `Download Dialog` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right click on a link and select `Save Link As` you will get the option to name the file as whatever you want.

Another option is the [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) extension. This gives you much more control over your downloads including renaming.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may not need an extension if all you are trying to do is just give a name to a file as you start to download it. In Firefox:

> See Tools > Options > General|Main : Downloads : "Always ask me where
>   to save every file"

Answer was taken from https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/749403#answer-31655.

Comment: Hi & Thanks, But I don't want to select the place (And see that `Save as` dialog); I want it just have a textbox that make me able to just rename the file (That makes the process easier)